# How should I get my inputAccessoryView to resize when rotating device?

Tags: ios, uitextview, uikeyboard

I'm attaching a `UIToolbar` to my `UITextView` as its `inputAccessoryView` in order to add a button to dismiss the keyboard. This works great and it looks correct when the device is in portrait mode. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to resize the toolbar to the lower height used for toolbars when the device is in landscape mode.

I'm adding the toolbar in my text view's delegate's `-textViewShouldBeginEditing:` method:

```
if (!textView.inputAccessoryView) {
    UIToolbar *keyboardBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    keyboardBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    keyboardBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];
    [keyboardBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spaceItem, doneButton, nil]];
    [spaceItem release];
    [doneButton release];

    [keyboardBar sizeToFit];

    textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardBar;
    [keyboardBar release];
}
```

I get strange behavior from this code in landscape mode, though. If I start editing in landscape mode, the toolbar has the landscape height but the Done button is drawn half off the screen. If I then rotate to Portrait mode, the Done button is drawn in the correct location, and it remains in the correct location when I rotate back to landscape mode.

If I start editing in portrait mode, the toolbar is drawn with portrait height, but the Done button is drawn in the correct location. If I then rotate to landscape mode, the toolbar remains portrait height, but the Done button is still drawn in the correct position at least.

Any suggestions for how to get this to resize when the device rotates? I'm really hoping there's a more automatic way than manually plugging in the height magic numbers in one of the view controller's rotation events.

Comment: You might find this of some use too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18926749/1633251

Answer (score 2):

That's a tough problem. I've solved this in the past by adjusting the frame when the accessory view gets laid out after rotating. Try something like this:

```
@interface RotatingTextInputToolbar : UIToolbar
@end

@implementation RotatingTextInputToolbar

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect origFrame = self.frame;
    [self sizeToFit];
    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y += origFrame.size.height - newFrame.size.height;
    self.frame = newFrame;

}
@end
```

And using the the `RotatingTextInputToolbar` instead of the `UIToolbar` in your code, above.

Comment: You definitely should **not** be setting `self.frame` inside `-layoutSubviews` as it can (does) cause `layoutSubviews` to get called recursively.

Comment: Mike Katz is right, jbrenan is wrong. It doesn't call layoutSubviews twice while setting it's frame inside -layoutSubviews

Answer (score 1):

Voila:

```
@interface AccessoryToolbar : UIToolbar @end

@implementation AccessoryToolbar

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self updateSize];
        NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self updateSize];
}

-(void)updateSize
{
    bool landscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);
    CGSize size = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size;
    if (landscape != size.width > size.height)
        std::swap(size.width, size.height);
    if (size.height <= 320)
        size.height = 32;
    else
        size.height = 44;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
}

@end
```

Comment: you should provide objective-c solution without `std::swap`