# UIBarButtonItem with custom view flexibly sized

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, uislider

Is it somehow possible to get a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view containing a UISlider to automatically resize similarly to a UIBarButtonItem using the system style UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace?

For example (for the sake of brevity I've left out setting frames and adding the toolbar as a subview to an existing view)

```
UISlider *slider = [UISlider new];
slider.minimumValue = 0;
slider.maximumValue = 1;
slider.value = 0.5

UIBarButtonItem *sliderItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:slider];
UIBarButtonItem *exampleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Example" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.items = @[sliderItem, exampleItem];
```

The idea being the toolbar is the full width of the screen, `exampleItem` can be a variable width due to localisation of it's title, and `slideItem` resizes similarly to `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` to take up the remaining space in the toolbar.

But the results are instead the slider stays taking up what ever frame you've given it (or the default/minimum frame if left out) and the next button just sits up against it.

I've tried the method mentioned in the following answer [make a UIBarButtonItem with customView behave like Flexible-Space item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773607/make-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-customview-behave-like-flexible-space-item) by changing the auto resizing mask of the slider, but it appears not to work (the question is about using a `UITextField` not a `UISlider` which is probably why.)

I've also tried using another `UIView` containing the `UISlider` as the custom view to intercept any `sizeThatFits` calls, but it in fact never gets called as I suspected.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without calculating the sizes of the button and spaces, and setting the slider's frame accordingly. Is there a reason you can't use a custom view rather than a UIToolBar so you can do this with constraints?

Comment: No there isn't a reason it could not be done that way really, I just assumed this might be a simple way of doing it having the UIToolbar handle most of it for you, but I guess that's not the case.